# Azure DevOps Process Merging

Tags: azure-devops

I am looking at an option where I may create a process on my Azure DevOps organisation by inheriting from one (say CMMI) and then also be able to get the work item types from Agile process rather than creating it of my own.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or do I need to create it manually?

Answer (score 0):

By reference to this doc: [Create an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#create-an-inherited-process), you can create an inherited process from any one of the four system processes: Basic, Agile, Scrum, or CMMI. However, an inherited process can only have one parent process.

Currently, if you want to use work item types from other process, please [add custom work item types (WITs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-work-item-type?view=azure-devops), and then [customize the workflow (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops).

Comment: This is what I want to avoid. Think of being able to add User Story to the inherited process from CMMI. The WIT details are already available and technically possible to be copied over. But that is not available as a feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you manage to implement this requirement, feel free to share it here so it can help others who have the same requirement. Thank you.

Comment: this I did a number of times, but this is not what I asked in my OP. If there is no other way, I shall have to do this again - which is quite meaningless but forced manual effort.

Comment: Currently we don't find other way to implement this requirement. Sorry for that.